# Animate an SVG element with velocity.js

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, draggable, velocity.js

***Here is the link of jsfiddle.  In the attached jsfiddle i have created a dragable SVG element using velocity.js .however dragging along both axis x and y  is very jerky .please advice.i am confused whether the mistake is on my part or velocity.js***

http://jsfiddle.net/KashifMKH/v1xx9nd1/6/

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
 document.addEventListener("mouseup", endMove);
 var click = false;

 var clickX, clickY;

 var moveX = 0,
     moveY = 0;

 var lastMoveX = 0,
     lastMoveY = 0;


 function mouseDown(evt) {

     evt.preventDefault();
     var element = (typeof(window.event) !== 'undefined') ? evt.srcElement : evt.target;
     if (element.id === "mycirc") {
         click = true;
         clickX = evt.clientX;
         clickY = evt.clientY;
     }
     document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveboth);
     return false;
 }

 function movexaxis(evt) {
     var clx = evt.clientX - clickX;
     moveX = lastMoveX + clx;
     return moveX;
 }


 function moveyaxis(evt) {
     var cly = evt.clientY - clickY;
     moveY = lastMoveY + cly;
     return moveY;
 }

 function moveboth(evt) {
     setTimeout(function move() {

         evt.preventDefault();

         var a = document.getElementById("mycirc");

         if (click) {
             movexaxis(evt);
             moveyaxis(evt);
             Velocity(a, {
                 translateX: moveX
             }, {
                 duration: "0ms"
             });
             Velocity(a, {
                 translateY: moveY
             }, {
                 duration: "0ms"
             });
             Velocity(a, "stop");
         }
     });
 }

 function endMove(evt) {
     click = false;
     lastMoveX = moveX;
     lastMoveY = moveY;
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate draggable element using velocity.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704974/animate-draggable-element-using-velocity-js)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you actually have set duration to `0ms` which cannot create any animation. Set it to `500ms` or similar and it will start animating smoothly. See http://julian.com/research/velocity/#arguments for more information on the arguments to set (like the easing and other stuff). Hope this helps.

Comment: its already to much slow movement .i have done this .its doesn't smooth the animation .it will create delay .which is our issue .i have to move faster .you notice that when you move fast, the circle will remain behind the cursor and move slowly to reach the mouse point .i have to solve this also .

Comment: Okay. Then you don’t need anything of Velocity. There’s nothing to animate in your case and the issue you’re seeing is likely a JavaScript method that isn’t performant enough to be instantly executed which is shown as delay.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference - this should not be using Velocity. This is trying to set position from the mouse, but Velocity is meant to perform smooth animations, so will set the position on the first animation frame after the value is set - meaning it can (and will) appear jerky at times. A duration of `0` will still not take effect till the next frame.

Set the values directly to prevent this happening:

```js
function moveboth(evt) {
     setTimeout(function move() {

         evt.preventDefault();

         var a = document.getElementById("mycirc");

         if (click) {
             movexaxis(evt);
             moveyaxis(evt);
             a.style.transform = "translate(" + moveX + "," + moveY + ")";
         }
     });
 }
```